# how can i repaint using different colors in a separate method?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

I am trying to use my fillCell method to be able to change the color based on what color was put in the parameter, however i dont know how to utilize graphics to change the color and repaint it and i am not importing objectdraw for this. I am trying to do this for a snake game i am trying to create. The class is meant to draw the grid, color the snake's body and head as well as clear the end of the snake and color the obstacles . So far i have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class GraphicsGrid extends JPanel
{
    private ArrayList<Point> fillCells;
    private int wid, hei, pix;
/**
 * Creates an arraylist and sets the default width, height and pixel
 * for a grid.
 */
    public GraphicsGrid() {
        fillCells = new ArrayList<Point>();
        wid = 400;
        hei = 400;
        pix = 10;
    }
/**
 * Creates an arraylist and sets the inputted width, height and pixel
 * for a grid.
 * @param width size of the width for the grid
 * @param height size of the height for the grid
 * @param pixel size for each cell 
 */ 
    public GraphicsGrid(int width, int height, int pixel) {
        fillCells = new ArrayList<Point>();
        wid = width;
        hei = height;
        pix = pixel;
    }
/**
 * fills and paints the current cell and creates the grid with lines
 * @param g creates an instance of graphics that has been imported
 */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Point fillCell : fillCells) {
            int cellX = (fillCell.x * pix);
            int cellY = (fillCell.y * pix);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(cellX, cellY, pix, pix);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, wid*pix, hei*pix);    

        for (int i = 0; i < wid*pix; i += pix) {
            g.drawLine(i, 0, i, hei*pix);
        }    

        for (int i = 0; i < hei*pix; i += pix) {
            g.drawLine(0, i, wid*pix, i);
        }
    }
/* *
 * adds a point to the cell and repaints the cell
 * @param x x-coordinate of the cell
 * @param y y-coordinate of the cell
 */
    public void fillCell(int x, int y, Color block) {
        Graphics g = new Graphics();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        fillCells.add(new Point(x, y));
        if(block.equals("black"))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            repaint();
        }
        else if(block.equals("red"))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            repaint();
        }
        else if(block.equals("white"))
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            repaint();
        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(Color.Green);
            repaint();
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

I cannot create another class file for this program either.

Comment: `"Edit: I cannot create another class file for this program either."` -- shouldn't this key bit of information have been part of your original question? Why this requirement?

Comment: This class was the reason to paint/repaint/color the grid and cells. I have done another program that utilizes most of this code to have an automatic moving red cell already. I am trying to make it so it would repaint different colors depending on the parameter.

Comment: No, why can't you create another class, like the Cell class that I have suggested? Do you have a requirements from your instructor? If so, show them to us please.

Comment: Our instructor told us to have only 6 class files which will be turned in which are the snake, snakemover, gamegrid, graphicsgrid, coord, and snakegame. The snake is obviously the snake itself that can move and obtain the head/tail/body coordinates, the snakemover commands the snake to move using the keylisteners, the gamegrid moves the snake on the grid showing the boundaries and adding obstacles, coord is the coordinates that the snake can move, and the snakegame is the jpanel that adds the grid, buttons, and other items

Answer (score 2):

`Graphics g = new Graphics();` Graphics is an abstract class, and so this will never work.

Suggestions:

- Create a Cell class, give it a Point and a Color field and any other fields it needs, and give it any getters/setters/constructors that it needs.
- Give Cell a `draw(Graphics g)` method that allows it to draw itself using its own Point's x and y and Color fields.
- Give your class above an `ArrayList<Cell>` and fill it as needed.
- In your `paintComponent` method override, iterate through the ArrayList above, calling `draw(g)` on each Cell in the ArrayList.
- I'm not sure why you've made your `paintComponent` method `synchronized` but that looks a bit sketchy to me, and I recommend that you get rid of that key word.
- Only call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within the `paintComponent` override method.
- Have you gone through the Graphics tutorials yet? If not I suggest you do so soon. You can find them at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).